# AccessDeniedException using spring security in Grails

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security

I have the following for a method within a controller:

```
  @Secured(['ROLE_ADMIN'])
  def signup ( SignupCommand cmd)
```

I have also added in the Config-core-sec.groovy:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
  '/signupApi/**' : ['ROLE_ADMIN']
]
grails.plugins.springsecurity.useBasicAuth = true
grails.plugins.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
   '/signupApi/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-exceptionTranslationFilter,-basicAuthenticationFilter
]
```

When I make a CURL Post request to test my API, I am getting an Access Denied Exception in the logs.

**CURL:**

```
curl --include \
     --request POST \
     --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
     --header "Accept: application/json" -u "moo@moo.com:12345" \
     --data-binary '{
```

**Stacktrace:**

```
[ERROR] 2014-10-14 19:31:28,672 [default] Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [] threw exception
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.AuthenticatedVetoableDecisionManager.deny(AuthenticatedVetoableDecisionManager.java:111)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.AuthenticatedVetoableDecisionManager.checkOtherVoters(AuthenticatedVetoableDecisionManager.java:103)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.AuthenticatedVetoableDecisionManager.decide(AuthenticatedVetoableDecisionManager.java:44)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:204)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:106)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:112)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.java:40)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.java:79)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:168)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:67)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
```

I have tried the user account and password in my database and am wondering what I could be doing wrong...

### Update

I made the change to Config.groovy but didn't change much. However, I made the following changes and it seems to have done something.

1. Removed entry from `grails.plugins.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules`.
2. Modified entry in chainMap to:

   `grails.plugins.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
          '/signupApi/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-exceptionTranslationFilter',
          '/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-basicAuthenticationFilter,-basicExceptionTranslationFilter'
       ]`

When accessing from browser I get a basic auth login dialog "Authentication Required...Grails Realm".

1. If I hit cancel, or enter wrong passwords, I get `HTTP Status 401 - Bad credentials`
2. If I enter the correct username and password, I get `HTTP Status 403 - Access is denied`

Based on your comment also I get the feeling something is going on with the ROLE.

Comment: What version of the plugin? Never heard of `Config-core-sec.groovy`. Ok, Google says it's been suggested by Some Dude on the internet as a way to externalize configs. Does this work if at least temporarily everything is in Config.groovy?

Comment: Hi, I'm out of my depth here since I'v inherited the config/project. What would be a good place to start debugging from? I've added breakpoints and noticed that deep down it says AnonymousUser instead of the user with the credentials I specify. Obviously, that means either I'm using incorrect credentials or the something is going on with the config. If it's advisable to simplify I can do so. In the config I see `spring-security-core:1.2.7.3`

Comment: Moving everything to Config.groovy as a test...

Comment: Actually, since it's and access denied, you're authenticated but you don't appear to have ROLE_ADMIN

Comment: @Burt Beckwith Thanks for the comment. After making the changes in the update I also had to add the appropriate ROLES. I can now reach the breakpoint within the controller.